# B2C - "Invalid password" when it is valid

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I'm trying to add local account sign in to my custom policy without adding local account sign up. I've created a local account sign up policy and used it to create a local account. Now, if I put those credentials into my custom policy, it doesn't work but the only error I get is "Invalid password". If I enter the same credentials into my built-in local account policy, it signs me in.

I even added sign up support to my custom policy, deleted my user, signed up through the custom policy, and tried to sign in with the credentials I just created: it still said "Invalid password". How can I troubleshoot this further? I've got app insights hooked up but the output isn't very helpful.

```
{
  "Kind": "HandlerResult",
  "Content": {
    "Result": false,
    "RecorderRecord": {
      "Values": [
        {
          "Key": "Validation",
          "Value": {
            "Values": [
              {
                "Key": "SubmittedBy",
                "Value": null
              },
              {
                "Key": "ProtocolProviderType",
                "Value": "SelfAssertedAttributeProvider"
              },
              {
                "Key": "TechnicalProfileEnabled",
                "Value": {
                  "EnabledRule": "Always",
                  "EnabledResult": true,
                  "TechnicalProfile": "login-NonInteractive"
                }
              },
              {
                "Key": "ValidationTechnicalProfile",
                "Value": {
                  "Values": [
                    {
                      "Key": "TechnicalProfileId",
                      "Value": "login-NonInteractive"
                    },
                    {
                      "Key": "MappingDefaultValueForClaim",
                      "Value": {
                        "PartnerClaimType": "client_id",
                        "PolicyClaimType": "client_id"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "Key": "MappingDefaultValueForClaim",
                      "Value": {
                        "PartnerClaimType": "resource",
                        "PolicyClaimType": "resource_id"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "Key": "MappingPartnerTypeForClaim",
                      "Value": {
                        "PartnerClaimType": "username",
                        "PolicyClaimType": "signInName"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "Key": "MappingPartnerTypeForClaim",
                      "Value": {
                        "PartnerClaimType": "password",
                        "PolicyClaimType": "password"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "Key": "MappingDefaultValueForClaim",
                      "Value": {
                        "PartnerClaimType": "grant_type",
                        "PolicyClaimType": "grant_type"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "Key": "MappingDefaultValueForClaim",
                      "Value": {
                        "PartnerClaimType": "scope",
                        "PolicyClaimType": "scope"
                      }
                    },
                    {
                      "Key": "MappingDefaultValueForClaim",
                      "Value": {
                        "PartnerClaimType": "nca",
                        "PolicyClaimType": "nca"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "Key": "Exception",
                "Value": {
                  "Kind": "Handled",
                  "HResult": "80131500",
                  "Message": "Invalid username or password.",
                  "Data": {}
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "Statebag": {
      "Complex-CLMS": {},
      "ComplexItems": "_MachineEventQ, REPRM, TCTX, S_CTP, M_EXCP"
    },
    "Exception": {
      "Kind": "Handled",
      "HResult": "80131500",
      "Message": "Invalid username or password.",
      "Data": {}
    },
    "PredicateResult": "False"
  }
},
```

Comment: Hi @sirdank. The common cause of this is misconfiguration of the **ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework** application. Have you [added this application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#register-an-application) and [configured the application identifier in your policy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#add-application-ids-to-the-custom-policy)?

Comment: @ChrisPadgett That was it, thank you. I was using the ID of my B2C application rather than my app registration. If you don't mind, would you post that and, if possible, include some information on how you arrived at your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common cause of this is misconfiguration of the **ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework** application in [the extension file](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml) of the custom policies.

You must ensure that:

1. You have [added the **ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework** application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#register-an-application) to your Azure AD B2C directory.
2. You have [configured the application identifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#add-application-ids-to-the-custom-policy), not the object identifier, of the **ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework** application in the extension file.

Configuration of the **ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework** application is important because [the **login-NonInteractive** technical profile](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/351aedd166aaa1f66695afa36cb45a6493336db3/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkBase.xml#L394) authenticates a local account by sending an access token request, using the resource owner password credentials grant type, to your Azure AD B2C directory.

Like all access token requests for an Azure AD directory, this access request must contain the application identifier of a client application (i.e. the **ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework** application) and that of a resource application (i.e. also the **ProxyIdentityExperienceFramework** application).

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that the correct Ids are assigned to the correct item in the [TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack/blob/master/LocalAccounts/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml)

I had the Ids swapped around because I assumed that they should be in the same order as they were [created in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom#register-identity-experience-framework-applications).

```
<Metadata>
    <Item Key="client_id">ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId</Item>
    <Item Key="IdTokenAudience">IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId</Item>
</Metadata>
<InputClaims>
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="client_id" DefaultValue="ProxyIdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId" />
    <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="resource_id" PartnerClaimType="resource" DefaultValue="IdentityExperienceFrameworkAppId" />
</InputClaims>
```